# Is my Turing Machine (Transition Function) correct for finding if a string is of even or odd length?

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I've been asked to create a formal Turing Machine (by means of a transition function) to which takes a string $a^n \in$ {a}* and decides whether it is an even or odd length.

What I have made is the following

({E, O, H}, {a, _, >}, P, E, {H})

Where P is

State, Letter $\to$ P(State/Letter)

E, a     $\to$ (O, _)

E, _  $\to$ (E, $\to$)

E, > $\to$ (E, $\to$)

O, a     $\to$ (E, _)

O, _  $\to$ (O, $\to$)

O, > $\to$ (O, $\to$)

I'm fairly sure I've got the right idea but I don't know how exactly I am meant to finish. How do I 'finish' and where in the input do I start reading from?

Comment: What is exactly the language that you want to decide? Also, your transition function is not well-defined: one has to specify the new state, the letter written on the tape, and the direction the head takes on the tape. Here you used sometimes $(E,\rightarrow)$ as saying "go to state $E$ and move to the right", and $(E, \_)$ as "go to state $E$ and put a blank on the tape".

Comment: I need to describe formally (by means of a transition function) a Turing machine which decides whether an input string $a^n \in$ {a}* is an even or odd length.

Comment: What is wrong with using  (E,→)  and  (E,_) ? It will create a space. Then as it then sees a space will move to the right?

Comment: @sam The problem is the transition function must specify _three_ things: The new state, if and what to write into the current box AND if and in what direction to move. That means writing a space and going right is $(s, \Box, \rightarrow)$ while writing a space and not moving is $(s, \Box, -)$ and writing nothing and moving right is $(s, -, \rightarrow)$. You can't write $(s, \rightarrow)$ because you must specify three things, i.e. an element from $S\times (\Sigma \cup \{-\}) \times \{\leftarrow, -, \rightarrow\}$

Answer (score 2):

Try to put more structure here: The states $\{E, O, H_E, H_O\}$ are meant to denote even, odd and halted even, odd states. The Alphabet may only consist of $\{a, \Box\}$ i.e. the letter and the blank.
The algorithm we think up is

```
switch (state)
case even:
    if letter == a then
        state = odd
        goRight
    else
        state = halt_even
    end if
case odd:
    if letter == a then
        state = even
        goRight
    else
        state = halt_odd
    end if
end switch
```

Now we can say the transition function is given by
$$(s,l) \mapsto \delta(s, l) = (s, l, d)\\
(E, \Box) \mapsto (H_E, -, -) \\
(E, a) \mapsto (O, -, \rightarrow) \\
(O, \Box) \mapsto (H_O, -, -) \\
(O, a) \mapsto (E, -, \rightarrow)$$

The halting states are $H_E, H_O$. Our TM is then given by
$$TM = (\{E, O, H_E, H_O\}, \{a, \Box\}, \delta, E, \{H_E, H_O\})$$
We consider two acceptance rules:

1. $TM$ accepts $a^{2n}$ iff the halting state is $H_E$ and
2. $TM$ accepts $a^{2n+1}$ iff the halting state is $H_O$.